# findBy throws error when field name contains underscore

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm having an Item class with a property named vendor_name as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="item_info")
public class Item {
    @Column(name="vendor_name")
    protected String vendor_name;
    /* Getter/Setter methods */
```

I'm trying to write a CRUDRepository interface to return Items based on vendor_name:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemDAO extends CrudRepository<Item, Integer>{
    public Item findByVendor__name(@Param("vendor_name") String vendor_name);
}
```

According to the docs, if there is an underscore in the property name,then we need to escape the underscore in the findBy method by adding an additional underscore. However, I'm still getting an error saying "no property named vendor found for type Item".

I cannot remove the underscore from the property. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: try to escape the underscore in the param annotation: `@Param("vendor\_name")`

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for your issue?

Comment: @Igor I was not able to fix the issue. I updated the name of the property to vendorName and used findByVendorName() instead.

Comment: @drunkenfist Thanks for the response.  Yeah, I ended up renaming/remapping my column too.

Answer (score 0):

From Spring Data JPA documentation:

> As we treat underscore as a reserved character we strongly advise to follow standard Java naming conventions (i.e. not using underscores in property names but camel case instead).